# Android Studio links tel: mailto: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL

Tags: android-studio

Se que es un tema antiguo ya, igual alquien me puede ayudar. Tengo el mismo problema. Estoy intentando crear una app de una pagina web, en android studio, y para los enaces mailto: tel: whatsapp: sale el error ERR_UNKNOWN_URL He probado el codigo de arriba pero sique dando el mismo error. Tambien sale un aviso de que shouldOverrideUrlLoading es obsoleto y viene tachado. He probado todas las soluciones para android N pero siempre con el mismo resultado.

Mi codigo es el siquente.

```
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 WebView mywebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mywebView.loadUrl("https://m.demo.es");
    WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}


public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            String url = request.getUrl().toString();
            if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                initiateCall(url);
                return true;
            }
            if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                sendEmail(url.substring(7));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url != null && ((url.startsWith("tel:")) || (url.startsWith("mailto:")) || (url.startsWith("https://api.whatsapp")) || (url.startsWith("http://api.whatsapp")))) {
                view.getContext().startActivity (
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```